# Accessing azure data lake folders from windows explorer

Tags: azure-data-lake, data-lake

It is possible to access Azure data lake folders from windows explorer through SMB or file share like we can do with Azure file storage?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, that is not possible.
You can try to write your own aplication to do it, but its not an easy job.
You can also use visual studio or azure portal to access your data.